# If $u \in C^1(\mathbb{R}^2)$ and $yu_x + (-3y-2x)u_y = 0$, then $u$ is constant.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

> Show that if $u \in C^1(\mathbb{R}^2)$ and $yu_x + (-3y-2x)u_y = 0$,
>   then $u$ is constant.
>
> Find a non constant solution defined in an open set $U \subset \mathbb{R^2}. $

I'm a little stuck, I tried to look at the characteristics equations but I couldn't see how it helps to prove that the solution is constant.

And I don't know how to prove that there exists a non constant solution

Can someone please suggest how do I proceed to solve this question?

Thanks

Comment: This looks like a good candidate for the [method of characteristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$yu_x-(3y+2x)u_y=0$$
HINT : Solving thanks to the method of characteristics.

System of characteristic ODEs : $\quad \frac{dx}{y}=\frac{dy}{-(3y+2x)}=\frac{du}{0}$

First characteristics family of cuves from $\quad \frac{dx}{y}=\frac{dy}{-(3y+2x)} \quad\to\quad \frac{dy}{dx}=-3-2\frac{x}{y}$

ODE of homogeneous kind $\to$ change of function $t(x)=\frac{y}{x}$ which reduces to a separable ODE. Solving it leads to:
$$\frac{(y+2x)^2}{y+x}=c_1$$
The second family of characteristic curves comes from $\frac{du}{0}$ implying $u=c_2$

The implicit form of the PDE general solution is $\Phi\left(\frac{(y+2x)^2}{y+x}\:,\: u\right)=0$ where $\Phi$ is any differentiable function of two variables. Or, on explicit form :
$$u(x,y)=F\left(\frac{(y+2x)^2}{y+x}\right)$$
where $F$ is any differentiable function.

Of course, the above general solution includes the particular case of $F=$constant function.

Comment: @Santos, JJacquelin, manipulating the proportions too: $$\dfrac{2dx+dy}{2x+y}=\dfrac{dx+dy}{2(x+y)}$$

Comment: @RafaBudria : Of course, obviously $\frac{dx}{y}=\frac{dy}{-(3y+2x)}=\frac{dx+dy}{-2(x+y)}$ . But only the last one can be integrated. That is why I didn't use this approach.